# Gluon android apk produces a black screen when tested with an emulator

Tags: javafx, gluon, gluon-mobile, javafxports

I followed the tutorial for the gluon mobile android setup, however, when creating an apk and running it on an emulator, a black screen shows and basically crashes the app. This is currently my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.10'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
}
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
jcenter()
maven {
    url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
}
mavenCentral()
}

mainClassName = 'com.gluonapplication.GluonApplication'

dependencies {

compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.4.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.9.0'
compile 'com.jfoenix:jfoenix:8.0.1'
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.1"

androidRuntime 'com.gluonhq:charm-down-core-android:3.7.2'



}

jfxmobile {
javafxportsVersion = '8.60.9'
downConfig {
    version = '3.7.2'
    // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
    plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage', 'pictures'
}
android {
    manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    androidSdk = "C:/Android/android-sdk"

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
        exclude 'META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }


}
ios {
    infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
    forceLinkClasses = [
            'com.gluonhq.**.*',
            'javax.annotations.**.*',
            'javax.inject.**.*',
            'javax.json.**.*',
            'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
    ]
    }
}
```

My adb logcat:

```
System.err: Exception in Application start method
04-21 01:58:12.247  3694  3718 I System.out: QuantumRenderer: shutdown
04-21 01:58:12.254  3694  3714 W System.err: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-21 01:58:12.255  3694  3714 W System.err:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-21 01:58:12.256  3694  3714 W System.err:    at javafxports.android.DalvikLauncher$1.run(DalvikLauncher.java:188)
04-21 01:58:12.256  3694  3714 W System.err:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
04-21 01:58:12.257  3694  3714 W System.err: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
04-21 01:58:12.257  3694  3714 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
04-21 01:58:12.257  3694  3714 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$138(LauncherImpl.java:182)
04-21 01:58:12.257  3694  3714 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$lambda$1(LauncherImpl.java)
04-21 01:58:12.257  3694  3714 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$2.run(Unknown Source)
04-21 01:58:12.258  3694  3714 W System.err:    ... 1 more
04-21 01:58:12.270  3694  3714 W System.err: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/time/LocalDate;
04-21 01:58:12.271  3694  3714 W System.err:    at javafx.scene.AccessibleAttribute.<clinit>(AccessibleAttribute.java:217)
04-21 01:58:12.271  3694  3714 W System.err:    at javafx.scene.Node$1.invalidated(Node.java:773)
04-21 01:58:12.271  3694  3714 W System.err:    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:111)
04-21 01:58:12.272  3694  3714 W System.err:    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
04-21 01:58:12.272  3694  3714 W System.err:    at javafx.scene.Node.setParent(Node.java:720)
04-21 01:58:12.272  3694  3714 W System.err:    at javafx.scene.Parent$1.onChanged(Parent.java:268)
04-21 01:58:12.273  3694  3714 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.collections.TrackableObservableList.lambda$new$17(TrackableObservableList.java:44)
04-21 01:58:12.273  3694  3714 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.collections.TrackableObservableList.access$lambda$0(TrackableObservableList.java)
04-21 01:58:12.273  3694  3714 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.collections.TrackableObservableList$$Lambda$1.onChanged(Unknown Source)
04-21 01:58:12.279  3694  3714 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:328)
04-21 01:58:12.280  3694  3714 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:72)
04-21 01:58:12.280  3694  3714 W System.err:    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:232)
04-21 01:58:12.280  3694  3714 W System.err:    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(ListChangeBuilder.java:482)
04-21 01:58:12.280  3694  3714 W System.err:    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(ListChangeBuilder.java:541)
04-21 01:58:12.280  3694  3714 W System.err:    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(ObservableListBase.java:204)
04-21 01:58:12.281  3694  3714 W System.err:    at javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase.addAll(ModifiableObservableListBase.java:102)
04-21 01:58:12.281  3694  3714 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.addAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:237)
04-21 01:58:12.281  3694  3714 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.addAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:103)
04-21 01:58:12.282  3694  3714 W System.err:    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.GlassPane.a(SourceFile:145)
04-21 01:58:12.282  3694  3714 W System.err:    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication.a(SourceFile:229)
04-21 01:58:12.282  3694  3714 W System.err:    at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication.start(SourceFile:224)
04-21 01:58:12.282  3694  3714 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$145(LauncherImpl.java:863)
04-21 01:58:12.282  3694  3714 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$lambda$8(LauncherImpl.java)
04-21 01:58:12.283  3694  3714 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$9.run(Unknown Source)
04-21 01:58:12.283  3694  3714 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$158(PlatformImpl.java:326)
04-21 01:58:12.283  3694  3714 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.access$lambda$6(PlatformImpl.java)
04-21 01:58:12.283  3694  3714 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$7.run(Unknown Source)
04-21 01:58:12.283  3694  3714 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$156(PlatformImpl.java:295)
04-21 01:58:12.284  3694  3714 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.access$lambda$18(PlatformImpl.java)
04-21 01:58:12.284  3694  3714 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$19.run(Unknown Source)
04-21 01:58:12.285  3694  3714 W System.err:    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:57)
04-21 01:58:12.285  3694  3714 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$157(PlatformImpl.java:294)
04-21 01:58:12.285  3694  3714 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.access$lambda$5(PlatformImpl.java)
04-21 01:58:12.286  3694  3714 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$6.run(Unknown Source)
04-21 01:58:12.286  3694  3714 W System.err:    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.runLoop(RunnableProcessor.java:93)
04-21 01:58:12.286  3694  3714 W System.err:    at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.run(RunnableProcessor.java:52)
04-21 01:58:12.286  3694  3714 W System.err:    ... 1 more
04-21 01:58:12.289  3694  3714 W System.err: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.time.LocalDate" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.gluonapplication-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.gluonapplication-2/lib/arm, /data/app/com.gluonapplication-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
04-21 01:58:12.290  3694  3714 W System.err:    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
04-21 01:58:12.290  3694  3714 W System.err:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
04-21 01:58:12.290  3694  3714 W System.err:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
04-21 01:58:12.291  3694  3714 W System.err:    ... 37 more
```

I even tried putting a new default project's apk and putting it into an emulator however, it still received the same error with the black screen

Comment: `LocalDate` is Java 8 API, but it is supported by JavaFXPorts. What Android platform are you using? Can you try 24 or superior?

Comment: I have tried android 25, 21, and installed it on an actual android device. They all have the same black screen with the logcat above.

Comment: How are you dealing with those huge dependencies? I just tried a simple project with them and after 40 minutes my Mac ran out of memory.

Comment: Not entirely sure, I set my heap size to 128mb and memory to 1024mb in my emulator. Is it the possibility that I have too many dependencies to load and that is why I am getting errors?

Comment: I used bigger memory settings, and it didn't work, and even if it did, building for almost an hour it is not convenient at all. Are you sure you need all those dependencies? Can't you use more fine grain ones?

Comment: Most of the firebase dependencies I need. The compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1' dependency is not needed so I excluded it. I need most of the other dependencies. Still came with the same output after installing the apk and running it.

Comment: How long it takes you to build the apk? How are your machine settings (RAM, CPU)?

Comment: Takes about 6-10 minutes to build the apk and around the same time to install it on an emulator. My RAM is 12GB and CPU is i7 2600.

Comment: Hi is there any lead to what might be the problem/how to fix it?

Comment: I've tried now on Windows, with a new mobile project and your build.gradle, and I can build the apk. Once installed on my Nexus 6 I don't get the black screen. Maybe you can post some code snippet related to the issue so I can reproduce it?

Comment: I don't think its the source code itself because when I tried with a default single view project it came up with the same error. I'm not sure how I can send a snippet because the code is longer than the stackoverflow comment limit. You can check the source code here though: https://github.com/Jkim-Hack/CBUSHackios

Answer (score 0):

Same issue I was getting in Android 10 devices, here is [link](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/issues/38)

This is a temporary solution.